# Laravel validation on Http request

Tags: php, laravel-5, postman

I wrote this part of Api:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
            'citizenship' => 'required',
            'country' => 'required'
    ]);
...
```

and I am sending a Post request with Postman not passing one of the required field and I don't see any error response, but it just redirect me to the home page of the application. How can I grab the error message?

Comment: Can you show your `validate` method and whole `store`?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
try{
    $result = YourModel::validate($attributes);
}catch (\Exception $e){
    throw $e;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel is pretty smart. If you set the field `Accept` to `application/json` from Postman. You will notice that you will get a response with a 422 HTTP status code along with all of the validation errors. Also (from the ["Validation" section of the Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation):

> When using the validate method during an AJAX request, Laravel will not generate a redirect response. Instead, Laravel generates a JSON response containing all of the validation errors. This JSON response will be sent with a 422 HTTP status code.

Take a look at the method responsible for sending back the response, you will understand why :)

```
public function response(array $errors)
{
    if ($this->expectsJson()) {
        return new JsonResponse($errors, 422);
    }

    return $this->redirector->to($this->getRedirectUrl())
        ->withInput($this->except($this->dontFlash))
        ->withErrors($errors, $this->errorBag);
}
```